# How to submit autocomplete select value into Textfield in Tapestry5?

Tags: java, autocomplete, selection, textfield, tapestry

I've got a Textfield with autocomplete and zoneUpdater mixins. Based on the typed value, I call service which returns new values for the autocomplete select. So far, so good. Big problem for me is that autocomplete select doesn't submit chosen value. I want to update different zone, based on this value. The way it works now is that I have to submit the whole form and reopen again. But that's not what customer wants, it should do it on fly without submitting the form. Is there any solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Tapestry5 Autocomplete (based on Prototype) or the Tapestry5-Jquery Autocomplete (based on JQuery) ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't mention .. I don't use jquery plugin at all.

Comment: Has anybody tried to solve this issue ever?

Comment: I think its based on this: http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/. I think what you need to use is the "afterUpdateElement" option. Doesn't look like it has been implemented in the Tapestry mixin though, but maybe you can set this option yourself in some way.

Comment: +1 for a good question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to update different zone, based on this value.

I 've tried to do this with your setup and actually worked but the drawback is that the value I get as the CHANGE event of the input is what the user typed (not what the user selected from the autocomplete list).

To get the value from selected from the autocomplete list (although I 've not tried it) you should use the [callback parameter of prototype's Autocompleter](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/). Take into account that in order to do this you should rewrite a new Autocompleter mixin of your own as the Tapestry's built-in autocomplete mixin is not honoring that callback parameter.

I 've also checked out the tapestry-jquery's Autocomplete mixin and although jquery's autocomplete supports a [autocompleteselect event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) tapestry-jquery is not handling it in it's instantiation.

I 've not checked the chenille kit autocomplete mixin which maybe can help you, I really don't know.

As far as I know you should develop your own Autocomplete mixin based on any of these and add to it the selected item event functionality.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to Ajax.Autocompleter. Eventually, it was not callback but rather afterUpdateElement hook, which I've used. It works for me now, I just have to sort out encoding. Thanks again.

Comment: You 're welcome..., really cool you could do what you wanted. cheers.